# Google Appengine Search API to Datastore Query

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-search-api

I construct the Search API data like

```
search.SearchResults(
results=
[
search.ScoredDocument(doc_id=u'4873035534303232', fields=[search.TextField(name=u'name', value=u'a'), search.TextField(name=u'description', value=u'b'), search.DateField(name=u'date', value=datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 16, 7, 21, 58, 188000)), search.TextField(name=u'author', value=u'test@example.com')], language=u'en', rank=130231318L), 
search.ScoredDocument(doc_id=u'5717460464435200', fields=[search.TextField(name=u'name', value=u'a b c'), search.TextField(name=u'description', value=u'c d e'), search.DateField(name=u'date', value=datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 16, 7, 21, 25, 965000)), search.TextField(name=u'author', value=u'test@example.com')], language=u'en', rank=130231285L), 
search.ScoredDocument(doc_id=u'5506354231902208', fields=[search.TextField(name=u'name', value=u'How about today?'), search.TextField(name=u'description', value=u"it's good"), search.DateField(name=u'date', value=datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 16, 7, 10, 13, 608000)), search.TextField(name=u'author', value=u'test@example.com')], language=u'en', rank=130230613L)
],
number_found=3L)
```

I didn't insert the blobKey to Search API, then I need to query of Datastore to get the blobKey. Each ndb article has a same doc_id as a ID.

So when I get the response of Search API, I have to query 3 times for

```
doc_id=u'4873035534303232', doc_id=u'5717460464435200', doc_id=u'5506354231902208'
```

I think this process is so bad. Quota will be exceed soon. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: enable billing to raise quote limits?

Comment: @PaulCollingwood Of course, someday I have to do that~! I want to know the optimization solution for it. Is it general solution?

Comment: Cannot understand your problem. After performing a search query you want to grab some extra data for each result from the datastore? Use `ndb.get_multi` or just de-normalize that data and store it in the search API for faster access.

Comment: oh, look into appstats if that's what you want to do. but as Dmitry says, it's just what you have to do to get the data.

Comment: @DmitrySadovnychyi You means `ndb.get_multi` is not expensive, right? I thought when I tried this process, API Call will be 3 call per page, it's not good solution. Google give us 1000 free queries per day, so I wonder the efficient solution. Now I got it. thx!

Comment: @DmitrySadovnychyi, please extend your comment into an answer -- it seems the OP has found it useful and thus might accept it and this issue be correctly shown as closed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ndb.get_multi` or just de-normalize that data and store it in the search API for faster access.

`ndb.get_multi` will use single batch to get all keys and use only N read operations. (0.05 Million Ops is Free)